# How do I creating a Route53 DNS record for my beanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'd like to create an internally well-known dns name that points to the ELB of my (internal ELBScheme) elastic beanstalk environment that's hosting an internal REST API.

I tried adding an .ebextensions entry that looked like this:

```
"eb-env-dns-name" : {
  "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSetGroup",
  "Properties" : {
    "HostedZoneName" : "mydomain.com.",
    "Comment" : "alias targeted to elastic beanstalk LoadBalancer.",
    "RecordSets" : [
      {
        "Name" : "eb-env.mydomain.com.",
        "Type" : "A",
        "AliasTarget" : {
            "HostedZoneId" : "ABC123XYZ",
            "DNSName" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBLoadBalancer","DNSName"] }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The idea being that I could then access my internal application by making REST calls against the domain "eb-env.mydomain.com".

It didn't fail, but didn't work either: nothing showed up in my hosted zone on Route53.

I'm having trouble finding useful documentation on this stuff - can anyone point me at an example of how I might do this with the .ebextensions mechanism?  Or should I be just scripting the DNS name up separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the alias target section can you try using Canonical Hosted Zone ID. Do you already have the following in the ebextension or am I missing something.

```
"HostedZoneId" : { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBLoadBalancer","CanonicalHostedZoneNameID"] }
```

Documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-getatt.html

Comment: That looks right to me too from the CloudFormation docs. It does not work for me for an Elastic Beanstalk stack ebextension config though. The stack fails to create with: `Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Template error: resource AWSEBLoadBalancer does not support attribute type CanonicalHostedZoneID in Fn::GetAtt`

Comment: The AWSEBLoadBalancer resource's attribute names depend on the ELB scheme used ("internal" or "internet-facing").  Use "DNSName" attribute instead and it works on both schemes.

Answer (score 1):

Realised I was going to the wrong way putting an environment specific resource into ebextensions (plus a bunch of other things wrong with the snippet in the question mean it would never work).

This is what I ended up with that works for my use case.  This way I get a unique URL per environment, based on the environment name (different, readable and obbviously named urls for integration, uat and production environments).

```
Resources: {
  "dnsResourceNname" : {
    "Type" : "AWS::Route53::RecordSet",
    "Properties" : {
      "HostedZoneName" : "mydomain.com.",
      "Comment" : "DNS name for envornment ELB.",
      "Name" : {
        "Fn::Join" : [ "", [
          { "Ref" : "AWSEBEnvironmentName" },
          ".mydomain.com."
        ] ]
      },
      "Type" : "CNAME",
      "TTL" : "900",
      "ResourceRecords" : [ { "Fn::GetAtt" : ["AWSEBLoadBalancer","DNSName"] } ]
    }
  }

}
```